# Why do I get a `trait bound `[T]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied when I try and implement Ord and Eq manually on unsized types?

Tags: rust, traits

When creating a struct which stores a DST (e.g., a raw slice), I can use the normal `#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd)]` facility to get implementations of this trait on my type:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct A([u8]);
```

However, if I implement them manually, then the compiler will complain that my type does not implement `Sized`:

```
struct A([u8]);

impl AsRef<[u8]> for A {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]>> PartialEq<S> for A {
    fn eq(&self, other: &S) -> bool {
        self.0.eq(other.as_ref())
    }
}

impl Eq for A { }

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]>> PartialOrd<S> for A {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &S) -> Option<Ordering> {
        let  slice: &[u8] = &self.0;
        slice.partial_cmp(other.as_ref())
    }
}

impl Ord for A {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(&other).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Compiler result:

```
rustc 1.12.0 (3191fbae9 2016-09-23)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:20:6
   |
20 | impl Eq for A { }
   |      ^^
   |
   = note: `[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required because it appears within the type `A`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq` for `A`
   = note: required by `std::cmp::Eq`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:29:6
   |
29 | impl Ord for A {
   |      ^^^
   |
   = note: `[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required because it appears within the type `A`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialOrd` for `A`
   = note: required by `std::cmp::Ord`
```

If I create a variant of the type which *does* have a fixed size (e.g. by turning it into a fixed-size array), then I can manually implement the traits no problem.

```
struct B([u8; 5]);

impl AsRef<[u8]> for B {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]>> PartialEq<S> for B {
    fn eq(&self, other: &S) -> bool {
        self.0.eq(other.as_ref())
    }
}

impl Eq for B { }

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]>> PartialOrd<S> for B {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &S) -> Option<Ordering> {
        let  slice: &[u8] = &self.0;
        slice.partial_cmp(other.as_ref())
    }
}

impl Ord for B {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(&other).unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Here is a playground link showing the issue](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1a26e92098a452952fbe95afd146c0ec&version=stable&backtrace=0).

My question is - how do I implement `Ord` and `Eq` on my custom DST, so that I can take advantage of the fact that I can `partial_cmp/eq` by any `AsRef<[u8]>`, but also use that to enforce the bounds for the `Ord`/`Eq` trait implementations, as I do with `struct B` in my example?

Comment: @matthieuM., The definition of the [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) trait requires `PartialEq`, so from my understanding I think it's okay for the `#[derive(PartialOrd)]` to require a `#[derive(PartialEq)]` as well.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't see what is wrong with that. `PartialOrd` requires `PartialEq`. The same thing happens with `struct A(u8);`.

Comment: @Dogbert: I got something weird at some point... but I am afraid I reduced it too much afterward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `S: AsRef<[u8]>` is also restricting `S` to `Sized` types by default. You need to use `?Sized` to opt-out of that.

> All generic type parameters implicitly have the `Sized` bound, so the `?Sized` can be used to opt-out of the implicit bound.

[From the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/unsized-types.html).

The following compiles fine for me:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct A([u8]);

impl AsRef<[u8]> for A {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]> + ?Sized> PartialEq<S> for A {
    fn eq(&self, other: &S) -> bool {
        self.0.eq(other.as_ref())
    }
}

impl Eq for A {}

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]> + ?Sized> PartialOrd<S> for A {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &S) -> Option<Ordering> {
        let slice: &[u8] = &self.0;
        slice.partial_cmp(other.as_ref())
    }
}

impl Ord for A {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(&other).unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fa88142288b2b455ce90b7e6bf0a67c7&version=stable&backtrace=0)